# Blazor Server App-JSinterop InvokeAsync Returns Null When Browser Window Loses Focus

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, blazor

Inside my OnAfterRenderAsync method, I have a timer being set that will eventually call a javascript function via an IJSObjectReference object:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        ...        
        mapModule = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./map-module.js");
        ...
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            TruckRefresh = new Timer(new TimerCallback(async _ =>
            {
                LocationRefresh? locationRefresh;

                int truckId = 0;
                try
                {
                    truckId = await mapModule.InvokeAsync<int>("getInfoWindowTruckId");                        
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    truckId = 0;
                }
                ...   
                

            }), null, 15000, 15000);

    }
}
```

If I move away from the browser window, the getInfoWindowTruckId method returns null causing the InvokeAsync method to throw a json parse exception. I tried returning int? but the same exception occurred.

Here's my javascript method:

```
export async function getInfoWindowTruckId() {

var truck = document.getElementById('truck-number');

if (truck) {
    return parseInt(truck.innerText);
}
return 0;

}
```

Is there a way to get InvokeAsync to return null without causing an exception?